# Sequelize: How to select subset of an array column?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, npm, sequelize.js

I have a table with an array column called `tokens`

I can query it via npm sequelize with no issues, Sometimes this column may have upto 20k elements in the array which i dont always need. I need just 10 elements from it

In SQL this would be

```
select tokens[:10] from schema.table
```

How I do this using sequelize ?

This is what I'm doing now

```
const whereClause = {
        where: { active: true },
        attributes: {
          exclude: ['tokens'],
          include: ['tokens[:10]'],
        },
      };

table.findAll(whereClause);
```

This gives the following error

```
original: error: column "tokens[:10]" does not exist
```

It is looking for a column named `"tokens[:10]"` instead of taking a subset.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you try using ```limit```? Like, ```limit: 10```

Comment: @vicki using limits I can limit the number of rows returned but can't limit the number of elements in the array column. Maybe I misunderstood what you said. Could you please share some sample code for that ?

Comment: Do something like this.
```const whereClause = {
        where: { active: true },
        attributes: ['tokens'],
        limit: 10
      };
```

Comment: @vicki I tired that, That only limits the number of rows returned. Not the number of elements on the tokens array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use literals when you select attributes in sequelize. You can try something like this,

```
    const whereClause = {
        where: { active: true },
        attributes: [
           [Sequelize.literal(`tokens[:${sub-array-length}]`), 'tokens']
        ]
      };

    table.findAll(whereClause);
```

Note the use of colons to denote the sub-array slicing index